# How to troubleshoot SharePoint 2013 people picker are resolving users from one domain with one way trust?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, people-picker

We have a one way trust with one domain. The users are not resolving for some reason in all our environments. initially we thought it could be a firewall issue and disabled the firewall and it started working in few environments but failed again. Didnt observe anything from verbose uls logs. We opened a MS case and they suggested to remove "Http activation" from server roles and features and add it again. But even that didnt fix the issue. How to troubleshoot it further?

Comment: It would be good if you could share what other troubleshooting you have done. Have you tested the ports? Trevor Seward created this nice tool https://github.com/Nauplius/PeoplePickerPortTester

Comment: yes, i tried it, it gave a list of open ports opened and closed ones, didnt understand how to make the best use of it. I can share the output here if that is of any help for troubleshoot. People picker was previously working and few times working now (Mostly after reboots). This issue occurred in all our environments.

Answer (score 1):

Hello try set PeoplePicker SearchADproperties with Powershell through STSADM. You will set here all AD domains and apropriate accounts for reading from AD.

```
stsadm -o setproperty -url http://<server:port> -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:contoso.corp.com,<LoginName>,<Password>;domain:bar.contoso.corp.com,<LoginName>,<Password>"
```

[MS documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/cc263460(v=office.12))

*Hope it helps!*